# Correlating messages on two Camel Routes

Tags: apache-camel

In my application I have a generic Camel Route such as the following

```
from("direct:something").to("direct:outgoing")
```

and then dynamically in my code I deploy another route:

```
from("direct:outgoing").process(processor)
```

When flowing from route 1 to route 2 a new Exchange will be created. Is there an idiomatic way to correlate both? Should I set EXCHANGE.Correlation_ID header on the first route before sending it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should definitely all be processed on the one exchange. Run this test and you'll see the same camel Exchange, with the same properties, etc.

```
public class CamelExchangeTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Processor showExchangeIdProcessor = new Processor() {
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                System.out.println(exchange.getExchangeId());
            }
        };

        Main camelMain = new Main();
        camelMain.addRouteBuilder(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("timer:foo?period=1s&repeatCount=1")
                        .log("excgabge created!")
                        .process(showExchangeIdProcessor)
                        .to("direct:outgoing")
                ;

                from("direct:outgoing")
                        .log("outgoing!")
                        .process(showExchangeIdProcessor)
                ;
            }
        });
        camelMain.run();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ID-MYPC-55760-1411129552791-0-2
ID-MYPC-55760-1411129552791-0-2
```

So something else is going on. When you say `"direct:outgoing"`, do you mean exactly that or is it something different - a different component perhaps?

When you say the route is created dynamically, how exactly is that done, and when (and why?)

Answer (score 1):

From the [Camel doc](http://camel.apache.org/correlation-identifier.html):

> Some EIP patterns will spin off a sub message, and in those cases, Camel will add a correlation id on the Exchange as a property with they key `Exchange.CORRELATION_ID`, which links back to the source Exchange. For example the Splitter, Multicast, Recipient List, and Wire Tap EIP does this.

Thus, `Exchange.CORRELATION_ID` is set by Camel and should not be set by your application. But feel free to set a custom header or property if you need to such as:

```
exchange.getIn().setProperty("myProperty", myIdentifier);
```